# How to use a submit input button as a link to another webpage in the current tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use an `<input type="submit">` button as a link to open another webpage in the current tab. I am using the attribute `multiple` but I want to display the select menu [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBNAs.png)

Here is my HTML:

```html
<form id="link">
    <select multiple="multiple" >  
     <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Моля изберете</option>
       <option value="volvo">Кардиолог</option>
    <option value="gastro.html" target="_blank">Гастроентеролог</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Ортопед</option>
    <option value="audi">Дерматолог</option>
    <option value="audi">Уролог</option>
 </select >
 <div class="btn">
 <button class="SubmitButton" type="submit" name="SUBMITBUTTON" value="Submit" onsubmit="return validateForm();" >Търси</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is my Javascript and jQuery:

```js
$('#link').on('submit', function (e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this),
        $select = $form.find('select'),
        links = $select.val();
    if (links.length > 0) {
        for (i in links) {
            link = links[i];
            window.open(link);
        }
    }
});
```

How do I rewrite my code so that when the user submits the form, the new webpage opens in the current tab instead of a new window?

Comment: Your question and code are very confusing. You mention Tabs yet I do not see any in your HTML. When you load the site, where do you want it to appear? In your page, or a new window?

Comment: I agree with @twisty that the question is a little confusing. That said, it appears you want to go to a new URL in your present tab and not a new one. To do that, change `window.open(link)` to `window.location = link`

Comment: I want it to appear for example at gastro.html but when i submit the form, it is opening a new tab. I dont want that to happen because if you submit it 5 times u gonna get 5 tabs at the top of the browser. Sorry for the confusion, this is my first question in stackoverflow :(

Comment: You could start improving your question quality by a simple way: indentation your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the behaviour of `window.open`. It's a user preference and browsing context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

But you could change your code. If it's an API, instead of open a new link you could just [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) this link and display the result somewhere.

But since it isn't look like an API... you could use some AJAX technologies to get its content and put it in an element at your current page (but it's look like a web at 2010).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to guess your question the answer should be:
Do a preventDefault and then disable the submit Button. Now you can open your "tab".
In this way, users can submit only once and cannot open new pages

Answer (score 0):

## Your Problem

In your Javascript, you used `window.open(link)` to open the link. But this Javascript function opens URLs in a new window. You want the URL to open in the current tab, not to open in a new window or new tab.

## My Solution

Replace this line in your code:

```js
window.location = link;
```

With this line:

```js
window.location.href = link;
```

This Javascript function stimulates clicking on a link.

Or simply replace your Javascript with the Javascript in my code snippet. I’ve also changed the `.on(‘submit’, function(e) {…});` function, which is outdated, with `.submit(function(e) {…});` which is the preferred method.

```html
    <form id="link">
        <select multiple="multiple" >   
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Моля изберете</option>
            <option value="volvo">Кардиолог</option>
            <option value="gastro.html" target="_blank">Гастроентеролог</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Ортопед</option>
            <option value="audi">Дерматолог</option>
            <option value="audi">Уролог</option>
        </select >
        <div class="btn">
        <button class="SubmitButton" type="submit" name="SUBMITBUTTON" value="Submit" onsubmit="return validateForm();" >Търси</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

```
    $('#link').submit(function (e) {
        // e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this),
            $select = $form.find('select'),
            links = $select.val();
        if (links.length > 0) {
            for (i in links) {
                link = links[i];
                window.location = link;
            }
        }
    });
```